# Optimize excel filter formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am currently working with a very big data, and trying to filter my data just like the formula in the photo.

I filtered my data with conditions that only suited for the first condition. My formula worked. But quite long. How to optimize this formula?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is much easier to help you, if you provide your data and expected output as text within your question - as well as the formula. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. At the best use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)

Answer (score 2):

You can use VLOOKUP to return the correct limits:

```
=FILTER(A2:C11,(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,E2:G4,2,FALSE)<=C2:C11)*(VLOOKUP(B2:B11,E2:G4,3,FALSE)>=C2:C11))
```

Note, I did not include the title in the ranges, it causes errors.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know, what if I'm I have the same condition, but I'll be using it to filter other data that extends to around 40 columns, how this formula works?

Comment: Your first reference would then include all the columns desired.